# How to move on vertical wall with gravity ticked for rigidbody

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigidbody

I am making a ball-rolling game. I want to implement an interaction where the ball can move on a specific area of a vertical wall like the game that the images show, but I don't know how to implement it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we'll create invisible trigger colliders covering the volume of your map where you want the gravity to point in a new direction. Rotate those colliders so that their "forward" direction (the blue arrow on the transform gizmo in local translation mode) points in the direction you want gravity to point.

[image: Example setup in Unity]

Create a [physics layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) called "Gravity Zone" and ensure these objects are on that layer. You can [filter collisions with this layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) so only objects that need to use this altered gravity detect overlaps with these objects - good for performance since you have fewer collisions to check, and it saves you some filtering code to manually ignore them in unrelated scripts.

Then we'll make a script for the rigidbody (or bodies) that should obey this altered gravity:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class VariableGravity : MonoBehaviour {

    // Reference to our attached body, for modifying our physics.
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector] Rigidbody _body;

    // Cache ID of gravity modification physics layer.
    LayerMask _gravityLayer;
    
    // Current gravity acceleration vector - default to normal gravity.
    Vector3 _gravity = Physics.gravity;
    
    // Collection of altered gravity zone trigger volumes we're touching.
    // These can overlap, so we store an ordered list of them,
    // where the last entry is always the most recent one we've entered.
    List<Collider> _zonesTouched = new List<Collider>();

    // Change our gravity to point in the provided direction.
    public void SetGravityDirection(Vector3 direction)
    {
        // We'll make our custom gravity exactly as strong as the default one.
        _gravity = Physics.gravity.magnitude * direction;
    }

    void Start() {
        _gravityLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Gravity Zone");
    }

    // Apply our gravity change every physics step.
    void FixedUpdate() {
        // If _gravity == Physics.gravity, then this is a no-op
        // (ie. we apply zero additional acceleration).
        // Otherwise, it undoes the normal gravity and applies our new gravity.
        _body.AddForce(_gravity - Physics.gravity, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }

    // When we enter a gravity zone, apply its changes to our gravity direction.
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        // Ignore triggers that are not gravity zones.
        if (other.gameObject.layer != _gravityLayer) {
            return;
        }

        // Add this zone to the end of our list.
        _zonesTouched.Add(other);
        
        // Use this zone's gravity as our current falling direction.
        SetGravityDirection(other.transform.forward);
    }

    // When we exit a gravity zone, remove its effect.
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        // Ignore triggers that are not gravity zones.
        if (other.gameObject.layer != _gravityLayer)  {
            return;
        }

        // When we leave a zone, we want to fall back on the effects
        // of the next-most-recent zone we touched, if any.
        int zoneCount = _zonesTouched.Count;

        if (zoneCount > 1) {
            // We have another zone to fall back on.
            // If "this" zone we're leaving is the one currently in effect,
            // fall back on the next most recent zone in the stack.
            if (other == _zonesTouched[zoneCount - 1]) {
                var fallback  = _zonesTouched[zoneCount - 2];
                SetGravityDirection(fallback.transform.forward);
            }
            // ...and remove the zone from our list, 
            // even if it wasn't the currently active one.
            _zonesTouched.Remove(other);
        } else {
            // No other zones in our list, revert to normal gravity.
            _zonesTouched.Clear();
            _gravity = Physics.gravity;
        }
    }

    // Automatically wire up the _body variable so we don't have to set it.
    void OnValidate()
    {
        // TryGet is a good habit for minimizing editor allocations,
        // plus it's less typing than out _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        TryGetComponent(out _body);
    }
}
```

Most of the complexity here is just in ensuring we handle entering/exiting multiple zones in any order - so if you have a funny-shaped volume to navigate, you can build it out of multiple colliders and this script will handle the transitions between them sensibly.